# OroCRM: import csv contacts function not working. How do I fix it?

Tags: import, orocrm

I'm stumped at first post with OroCRM because I can't import data. I've tried using the template to test an import but it just tells me "Import started successfully. You will receive an email notification upon completion." and then I get nothing back. No new records are visible. I don't get any statistics back from the import attempt either to tell me nothing has been imported.

There's no step-by-step manual for the community version so would really appreciate some noob-friendly pointers on the basics!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local instance, make sure [the message consumer is running](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/#configure-and-run-required-background-processes) and validate [the email transport configuration](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/parameters-yml/).